# Custom libraries and dependency injection

Tags: 8, theming

I have been using D7 for a while, new to D8; also have a fair amount of experience with Laravel/Lumen and dependancy injection (DI).  One of the big sell's of D8 is the new OO structure, and specifically the Symphony DI system.

So to test this out, I want to develop (port some of my old D7 code) to a D8 custom library, that will 'inject' when needed, and I do not want to do this as a module (I got that right; the objective is to have a PHP library class).

Given some of the documentation I read, I created a folder called `/libraries/my_library`, and for the hell of it I added a PSR4 mapping to /composer.json like so:

`"Drupal\\CustomLib\\": "libraries"`

For the record, I tried it without `Drupal\\` as well - makes no difference.

In `/libraries/my_library/scr/myClass.php` I have a single class `myClass`.  I also added a my_library.services.yml

services:

```
  myClass:
    class:   CustomLib\mylibrary\myClass
```

And in my custom theme file I simply tried

```
use CustomLib\mylibrary;

function quirk_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $tools = Drupal::service('myClass');
}
```

which results in

`Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service`

Can someone point me in the right direction please.  What am I missing.  I am assuming Drupal is not scanning the /libraries/my_library folder for the services definition - but how do I get it to do so?

Comment: In Symfony you always(maybe "traditionally" is the better word?) need a bundle to register a library as a service, they don't register themselves. I imagine it's the same for Drupal with a module (or maybe theme), in that you'll need a module to make the service available to Symfony. Makes sense when you think about it - your library shouldn't "know" that it's going to be eventually used in a Symfony service, it should just do what it does and do it well.

Comment: I think you might be right.  Found this post :  http://achilleskal.com/blog/service-container-for-drupal-geeks.  This does beg the question - how will we be able to use PHP libraries that are not available through composer.

Comment: Which libraries would those be though? Composer can download any GitHub project which surely covers 99.99% of cases, and for anything else it's pretty configurable. If you mean an offline library that for some reason can't be made available over a network or the local disk, then yeah, you're going to struggle. But that would be true of any php project

Answer (score 2):

OK people, I played around with a couple of options, but the bottom line is, if you want to create your own 'services' class, specifically for dependancy injection, it has to be tied to a module.

So - I created a custom module.  The actual module file is empty

```
<?php
```

Also created the services definition / config file `my_module.services.yml` and then critically, your services class files should go in a sub-folder /src.  Since it is a service, you will need an interface and implementation class.

Comment: You don't technically need an interface. It is also possible to define the class in a separate library, pull in the library via composer, and write a module that just defines a service pointing to that class.

Comment: @mradcliffe: please tell me more.

Comment: Here are a couple of examples: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/currency/tree/currency.services.yml#n21, http://cgit.drupalcode.org/xero/tree/xero.services.yml#n11. The service definition is set to a class that is not packaged with the module, but is brought in via composer dependency. In the first case, @Xano maintains a generic PHP library for currency metadata and then also maintains a drupal module with drupal-specific implementations. In the second case, I do the same thing, and the XeroClient class does not specifically implement an interface, it extends a class (but that's irrelevant).